# guava and bonecp in webstart giving security exception

Tags: guava, bonecp

I have an APP that is run via java webstart. It is using the BoneCP library which is dependent on the Google guava library. When it starts to down load it fails on the guava jar file. Antiviruses blocks the download giving me the following.[Security Exception](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=25642)
Anyone else have this issue?
Thanks for any help!